# Argument not Optional - Simple VBA function

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting the Argument not optional compiler error in vba and can't figure out why.

I can't see any typos, I don't even take any arguments and the subroutine only executes on a button click.

```
Public Sub SearchAMLinesForIDs_Click()
    Dim time As String
    time = "AM"

    Dim end_row As Long
    end_row = Range("A2").End(xlDown).row


    Dim lookup_end_row As Long
    Dim lookup_result As Long

    lookup_end_row = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(time & "_Lines").Range("A2").End(xlDown).row

    lookup_table = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(time & "_Lines").Range("A2:C" & lookup_end_row)

    Dim row As Long

    For row = 1 To end_row
        lookup_result = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("A" & row), lookup_table, 1, False)

        Cells(row + 1, 2) = lookup_result
    Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out the `lookup_result` line and see if it compiles.  If it does, you're missing a vlookup function parameter.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of parameters there. Are there too many?

Comment: `False` is inside the wrong set of parentheses.  Also that whole line is likely to fail, having a bunch of unqualified Range/Cells calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Sub SearchAMLinesForIDs_Click()

    Dim sTime As String, shtData As Worksheet, sht As Worksheet
    Dim lookup_result, rngLookup As Range
    Dim rw As Long

    sTime = "AM"
    Set shtData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sTime & "_Lines")
    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    Set rngLookup = shtData.Range(shtData.Range("A2"), shtData.Cells(shtData.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

    For rw = 2 To sht.Range("A2").End(xlDown).row

        'don't use Worksheetfunction, but test the return value for errors...
        lookup_result = Application.VLookup(sht.Cells(rw, 1), rngLookup, 1, False)

        sht.Cells(rw, 2) = IIf(IsError(lookup_result), "NoMatch!", lookup_result)

    Next rw

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize your object browser if you're running into issues like this.

[image]

You can test your vlookup within a cell in a worksheet to verify validity.

Answer (score 0):

Your parenthesis are in incorrect order.

```
lookup_result = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(1 + Row, 1), _
                                          ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Time & "_Lines").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lookup_end_row, 1)), _
                                          1, _
                                          False)
```

parenthesis opened for Range doesn't close and closed in the end.